# Most concise way to fold tree structures

Tags: code-golf, functional-programming, haskell

### Background (F#)

Let there be trees:

```
type Tree<'T> = Node of 'T * Tree<'T> list
```

Now lets fold them nicely with a function called...

```
foldTree f:('a -> 'b -> 'c) -> g:('c -> 'b -> 'b) -> a:'b -> t:Tree<'a> -> 'c
```

...taking two functions `f` and `g`, an initial state `a` and of course a tree structure `t`. Similar to the well known function [fold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)) which operates on lists, this function should "merge" siblings with `g` and parents with their children with `f` resulting in an accumulated simple value.

### Example (F#)

The tree...

```
//      1
//     / \
//    2   3
//   / \   \
//  4   5   6

let t = Node (1, [Node (2, [Node (4, []); Node (5, [])]); Node (3, [Node (6, [])])])
```

...passed to `foldTree` with the operators for addition and multiplication along with the initial state `1`...

```
let result = foldTree (+) (*) 1 t
        // = (1 + ((2 + ((4 + a) * ((5 + a) * a))) * ((3 + ((6 + a) * a)) * a)))
        // = (1 + ((2 + ((4 + 1) * ((5 + 1) * 1))) * ((3 + ((6 + 1) * 1)) * 1)))
```

...should return the value `321` to `result`.

### The Challenge

In any programming language, define the function `foldTree` in the most concise way you can come up with. Fewest number of characters wins.

Comment: I don't understand how folding is being generalized to trees. In what order do the mergings happens? Could you please give a worked example? Also, are our answers allowed to use imperative constructs?

Comment: @xnor each subtree is folded recursively; then the list of results is folded by a right-fold of `g` with starting value `a`, and combined with the node's value through `f`. Judging by the types.

Comment: Please some more examples?

Comment: @xnor, personally I'm most interested in functional approaches. However, I will not dismiss any answer using other programming paradigms.

Comment: @edc65, I extended the example a little bit. Hope that clears things up for you.

Comment: The title seems to conflict with the statement *In any programming language...*

Comment: That's correct. I changed it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Haskell, <s>37</s> 35:

```
data T a=a:*[T a]

(f%g)z(x:*t)=x`f`foldr(g.(f%g)z)z t
```

not counting the type definition. With it, <s>54</s> **52** (shortened by using infix operator, similarly to the answer by *proud haskeller*, but in a different way).

Ungolfed:

```
data Tree a = Node a [Tree a]

foldTree :: (a -> b -> c) -> (c -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> c
foldTree f g z (Node x t) = f x $ foldr (g . foldTree f g z) z t
                       -- = f x . foldr g z . map (foldTree f g z) $ t

--      1
--     / \
--    2   3
--   / \   \
--  4   5   6

t = Node 1 [Node 2 [Node 4 [], Node 5 []],
            Node 3 [Node 6 []]]

result = foldTree (+) (*) 1 t   -- ((+)%(*)) 1 t        {-
       = 1 + product [2 + product[ 4 + product[], 5 + product[]],
                      3 + product[ 6 + product[]]]
       = 1 + product [2 + 5*6, 3 + 7]
       = 321                                            -}

   -- product [a,b,c,...,n] = foldr (*) 1 [a,b,c,...,n] 
   --     = a * (b * (c * ... (n * 1) ... ))
```

This is the `redtree` ("*red*uce *tree*") function from John Hughes paper, "Why Functional Programming Matters", where it is presented in a more verbose formulation.

Comment: Interesting... I'm looking at the paper right now, but I can't find this particular definition of `foldtree` in there. Are you referencing the version of the paper published in “Research Topics in Functional Programming” ed. D. Turner, Addison-Wesley, 1990, pp 17–42.?

Comment: Ok, that's basically the same three-liner he gave in the updated version of the paper.I found this shortcut with `foldr` while learning functional programming with Hughes' paper and was wondering why he didn't use it. Especially considering that his defintion of `foldtree` is a bit loose about types there. Turns out my finding wasn't that special after all :(

Comment: change that frowny to smiley and all will be okay! :) it's good that you discovered this yourself too. the paper was first written very long time ago, in 1984.

Comment: 2 bytes to save: use an infix constructor instead of `N`, e.g. `:#` and  `f x$...` instead of `f x(...)`.

Comment: interestingly, when i was thinking of my solution, I came up with that improvement too but I dropped it because the two improvements couldn't be used together. oh well.

Comment: although, I did not think of putting `f` in infix when using that improvement.

Comment: you had a great idea. I've remembered seeing somewhere that using infix operators is one of known golfing techniques for Haskell. you're correct, it's either this way, or your way. Using infix `f` brings no savings in char count, but it is cleaner looking than `f x$`.

Answer (score 5):

## F#, <strike>70</strike> 61

```
let rec r f g a (Node(n,c))=f n<|List.foldBack(g<<r f g a)c a
```

Not going to win the contest, but I think you can't get less with F#

Answer (score 4):

## Haskell, 35

```
data T a=a:>[T a]
h(%)g a(e:>l)=e%foldr(g.h(%)g a)a l
```

the data type declaration is not counted.

Answer (score 3):

## Prolog, 85

Logic programming

```
b([],A,A). b([E|N],A,R):-b(N,A,T),c(E,A,Y),g(Y,T,R). c((C,S),A,R):-b(S,A,T),f(C,T,R).
```

Ungolfed

```
b([],A,A).
b([Element|Siblings],A,R):-
      b(Siblings,A,RSiblings),c(Element,A,RElement),
      g(RElement,RSiblings,R).

c((Parent,Children),A,R):-
      b(Children,A,RChildren),f(Parent,RChildren,R).
```

Functions f and g

```
f(A,B,R):-R is A+B.
g(A,B,R):-R is A*B.
```

Example

```
c((1,[(2,[(4,[]),(5,[])]),(3,[(6,[])])]),1,R).
```

[Try it online](http://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/QzXQJITa.pl)

Edit: correction of error signaled by [Will Ness](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/5021/will-ness), thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 48

```
Head@#~#2~Fold[##3,#0[x,##2]~Table~{x,List@@#}]&
```

Example:

```
In[1]:= foldTree = Head@#~#2~Fold[##3,#0[x,##2]~Table~{x,List@@#}]&;

In[2]:= foldTree[1[2[4[], 5[]], 3[6[]]], Plus, Times, 1]

Out[2]= 321
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 62

Javascript seems functional enough, function objects can be easily defined and passed as parameters.

Define a node as an object {v:value, c:list of children}, the example tree is:

```
t={v:1, c:[{v:2,c:[{v:4},{v:5}]},{v:3,c:[{v:6}]}]}
```

(here the `c` is optional. Making `c` a mandatory field with value [] if there are no children, the fold function can be 5 chars shorter)

and the fold function is:

```
F=(t,a,f,g)=>{
  var r=a
  t.c && t.c.forEach(t=>r=g(r,F(t,a,f,g)))
  return f(t.v,r)
}
```

**Golfed** (there is little to golf)

```
F=(t,a,f,g,r=a)=>(t.c&&t.c.map(t=>r=g(r,F(t,a,f,g))),f(t.v,r))
```

**Test** In Firefox

```js
t={v:1, c:[{v:2,c:[{v:4},{v:5}]},{v:3,c:[{v:6}]}]}

F=(t,a,f,g,r=a)=>(t.c&&t.c.map(t=>r=g(r,F(t,a,f,g))),f(t.v,r))

document.write(F(t, 1, (a,b)=>a+b, (a,b)=>a*b))
```